# Filter Sprout Forms entries based on field value, using parameters

Tags: entries, filter, entrymodel, plugin-sproutforms

I'm trying to display form entries from Sprout Forms that match a specific criterium:

```
{% for formEntry in craft.sproutForms.entries.formHandle('formHandle').fieldname('fieldvalue') %}
    {{formEntry.fieldname}}
{% endfor %}
```

This does not filter the entries.

This works:

```
{% for formEntry in craft.sproutForms.entries.formHandle('formHandle') %}
    {% if fieldname == 'fieldvalue'%}
        {{formEntry.fieldname}}
    {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```

Can this not be done with parameters, or am I using the wrong Entry model?

Comment: PS; I assume fieldname should be fieldhandle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filtering entries is now possible as of [Sprout Forms v2.2.0](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms/updates#release-v2.2.0):

```
{% for formEntry in craft.sproutForms.entries.formHandle('contact').firstName('Zoe') %}
  ...
{% endfor %#}
```

Comment: I've updated, but can't test it because now it produces an error in the assets field. see my support mail

Comment: Updated to 2.2.1 and everything works like expected now :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work...

```
{% for formEntry in craft.sproutForms.entries.formHandle('formHandle').search('fieldname:fieldvalue') %}
    {{formEntry.fieldname}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This only works partly. "search('fieldvalue')" works, but is insufficient. search('fieldname:fieldvalue') returns nothing. PS; I think it should be fieldhandle, but that gives the same results.

Comment: With the latest update to 2.2.1 this now works like it should, thanks